# C# based Marketing-API for Facebook - Problem with /adsets

Tags: c#, facebook, api, webclient

i got a questions.. Are there any Marketing-API Experts in here? Im trying to code a C# based API to create /campaigns, /adsets and /ads. With /campaigns i have no problem, after i start my project the created /campaign appears in my campaigns manager. But somehow it won't work with creating /adsets. I get a 400 bad request from Visual Studio. Does someone know the required fields to create an /adset?

Thanks in Advance!

```
string campaign_id = "8890374892378023";

NameValueCollection request_parameter = new NameValueCollection();
request_parameter.Add("name", "TestAdSet");
request_parameter.Add("optimization_goal", "REACH");
request_parameter.Add("billing_event", "IMPRESSIONS");
request_parameter.Add("bid_strategy", "LOWEST_COST_WITHOUT_CAP");
request_parameter.Add("is_autobid", "true");
request_parameter.Add("lifetime_budget", "1000000");
request_parameter.Add("campaign_id", campaign_id);
request_parameter.Add("targeting", "{'geo_locations':{'countries': ['DE']}},{'publisher_platforms': ['all']}, {'facebook_positions': ['all']},{'device_platforms': ['all']}");
request_parameter.Add("promoted_object", "{'page_id': ['78686786786786']}");
request_parameter.Add("start_time", "2019-04-11T15:00:17+0000");
request_parameter.Add("end_time", "2019-04-15T04:45:17+0000");
request_parameter.Add("status", "PAUSED");
request_parameter.Add("access_token", access_token);

byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_" + ad_account_id + "/adsets", "POST", request_parameter);
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);

string adset_id = Regex.Match(result, "[0-9]+").Value;

Console.Write(result);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Does following help? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign

Comment: Thanks for your comments mates!
jdweng, i am using exactly those docs. At the moment im not getting /adsets started.Too sad facebook stopped c# support.

Comment: guys, i got it. it was the problem which mjwills told me. the value of targeting needs to be correct json. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
request_parameter.Add("targeting", "{'geo_locations':{'countries': ['DE']}},{'publisher_platforms': ['all']}, {'facebook_positions': ['all']},{'device_platforms': ['all']}");
```

is incorrect, since the second string is not valid JSON. Be sure to check the string in https://jsonlint.com before using it, to make sure it is valid.